# Occluded texturing

Tags: texturing

Hope everybody is fine and everything is going well. I have a 1 million dollar question about " how to add a texture in the occluded area of a model".

For the entire week i try to figure it out procedural but fail.

Any idea ?

I put an image reference with the red line where i want to put the dust.

[image]

Comment: so if I answer this will I get a million dollars?

Comment: Yeah of course man. I have tons of monopoly money no problem.

Comment: Have you tried using pointiness?

Comment: This video may answer your question ... but hmm not sure if it will but sure sound like what you are looking for ... dirtmap creation there you go .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrb716STIlw

Comment: If you're asking about an AO node to be used as a factor, I asked this question before, and the answer was no, not without baking the AO, this is on the to do list for Blender but haven't been done

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51164/using-ambient-occlusion-as-a-factor-in-material-node-editor

Comment: I am confused by your question, since the shaded areas of your model entirely depends on your light setup. Are you trying to ask whether or not a texture can change depending on the light setup? And what exactly is the light setup? No ambient occlusion?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (as cegaton mentioned above)
UPD: mix two shaders by factor of Pointiness.
 [image]

Comment: Please don't answer a question with another question and explain what we're supposed to learn from the image.

Comment: No the pointiness allows to texture the edges of a object. What i'm talking about is be able to put texture in the occluded part (where the shadows are) like this: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/5pspjVd.png

Comment: @iamdemsugar does it mean that material should behave differently depending on whether or not it receives direct light?.. since we aren't talking about edges.

Comment: No this is just an additional touch i want to put on the material. Just dust like it doesn't move for a long time.

Comment: Those areas in fact are edges, inversed though.