# Cycles, Using Ambient Occlusion as a Factor in Material Node Editor

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image]I'm trying to give cavities a different shader in between adjacent objects "Dirt Map", I tried using Geometry Node, linking the Pointiness to Color Ramp to the Factor in a Mix Shader, as per the image above. The problem is, this works just fine within the mesh itself, but it wont capture cavities between different objects, I tried merging the meshes into one object using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, but that didn't change the result. Logically I tried to use Ambient Occlusion as a Factor for the Mix Shader, but Ambient Occlusion is a Shader, not a value provider node, is there a way to capture the value from AO shader to use it for Factor, or is there a completely different way to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to bake the AO to an image texture, then use the texture as your mix factor. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599

Comment: I was afraid someone's gonna say that :) I have lot's of objects, baking AO would take forever "may be it's just me", I just hope there was a way to get the same value that the AO shader provides, thank you anyways @gandalf3 , appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately not.. It's been a feature on the [todo list](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/ToDo) for ages, but no one has gotten around to it yet it seems.

Comment: Cycles now supports the Ambient Occlusion node.

Comment: Yes, now it does, thank you for bringing that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the node editor <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then under input you'll find Ambient Occlusion, the node itself shows in the image above, you can use AO output as a factor to feed to a Mix Shader node or a MixRGB node or... whatever you would use a factor for.

Comment: Can you expand this a bit. "it's in Input category" does not offer much help to anyone. PS does not matter if blender changed since you asked the question, any answer that is valid now is useful.

Comment: You're right @David I hope the answer makes more sense now

Comment: Much better. For the record I did not DV it.